# Java Spring JPA insert into

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Подскажите как выполнить: `insert into journals (messageid, oldowner) select id,owner from message where id = 1;`

В Postgres есть таблица message:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class Message implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "owner")
    private String owner;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "message", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set <Journal> journals;
```

и journals:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "journals")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "messageid")
public class Journal implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "oldowner")
    private String oldowner;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "messageid", nullable = false)
    private Message message;
```

Например, такой запрос работает:

```
@Transactional
public interface MessageModify extends CrudRepository<Message, Long>{
    @Modifying
    @Query("update Message m set m.owner = ?1,  m.text = ?2, m.sn = ?3, m.author = ?4, m.invid = ?5 where m.id = ?6")
    String setFixedOwnerFor(String owner, String text, String sn, String author, String invid, Long id);
}
```

А такой нет:

```
@Transactional
public interface JournalAdd extends CrudRepository<Message, Long> {
        @Modifying
        @Query(value = "INSERT INTO Journal (messageid, oldowner) select m.id, m.owner from Message m where m.id = ?1;", nativeQuery = true)
        String updateJournalOldowner(Long id);
}
```

Мой обработчик запроса:

```
@Autowired
private JournalAdd journalAdd;
@PostMapping("/update")
public String modifyowner (
@RequestParam String owner,
 @RequestParam String sn,
@RequestParam String text,
@RequestParam String invid,
@RequestParam Long id,
@RequestParam String author,
Map<String, Object> model) {
  Message messages = new Message (owner, id, sn, text, author, invid);
    messageModify.save(messages);
    journalAdd.save(messages);
    model.put("messages", messages);
    return "redirect:/main";
}
```

Comment: У вас в запросе `INSERT INTO Journal` а в сущности вы описываете таблицу `journals`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создание таблицы:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "journals")
public class Journal implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "newowner")
    private String newowner;
    @Column(name = "messageid")
    private Long messageid;
    @Column(name = "date", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
    private java.util.Date date;
```

Обработчик запроса:

```
    @PostMapping("/update")
public String modifyowner (
        @RequestParam String owner,
        @RequestParam String sn,
        @RequestParam String text,
        @RequestParam String invid,
        @RequestParam Long id,
        @RequestParam String author,
        Map<String, Object> model) {

    Journal journal = new Journal();
    journal.setMessageid(id);
    journal.setNewowner(owner);
    journal.setDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    journalAdd.save(journal);
```